# Why are LEGO slope bricks textured?

Tags: piece-information

Why is the slope part of bricks textured instead of the usual flat & glossy edge?

Are there any non-textured forms of these bricks?

[image: http://www.findmybrick.com/product_info.php?cPath=54&products_id=2507&osCsid=5bb0fc8763e1795781da8eb4f8dd2407]

Comment: Not all slopes are textured - for example the 1x2x2/3 30° slope is not textured, nor are every non-linear slope I can remember. All the textured ones I can remember are 45° or greater though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is likely a hold-over from when these were used primarily as roof pieces, and the texture provided some realism to the house/building sets.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure of why these slopes were originally textured; as Granpappy [points out](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/234) it's likely the texture was used to give roofs a nicer effect. I seem to remember something about the mould being easier to create that way (since less precision was required on the textured part), but it may just be my imagination.

However, a few years back slopes without that texture started to appear (and I'm talking about regular 45° ones, not newer parts like the cheese slope), and fans weren't too happy about it. After checking with LEGO, it appeared that the change wasn't really intentionnal but that LEGO didn't think it would matter, considering the parts kept the same functionality despite of the aesthetics being different.

At that point, LEGO confirmed that future slopes would continue to be textured (again, depending on which part), but that the stock of smooth ones would still be used so that it could take a while before it was depleted.

You may want to read [this lugnet discussion](http://news.lugnet.com/ambassadors/?n=313&t=i&v=a) on the topic.

Comment: "slopes without that texture started to appear" That sounds quite interesting, and I would like to read up on that, but the linked lugnet discussion lacks this detail.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your secondary question:

> Are there any non-textured forms of these bricks?

[1x1 30° slopes (cheese slopes)](https://brickset.com/parts/design-50746) are un-textured (just like [their 1x2 version](https://brickset.com/parts/design-85984)).

[image: Cheese slope]