# Are both of these slope designs genuine LEGO?

Tags: piece-information

[image: Different slope textures]

Are both of these slope designs genuine?

I am reasonably certain that this is just a mold change at some point, but it doesn't hurt to ask.  I also have two textured types in dark blue, and one smooth type in sand blue.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like it could be either [#3049](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3049) or [#3049c](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3049c). Part #3049 currently exists in Sand Blue in [at least three sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3049&colorID=55&in=A). As for the change in smooth and rough texture you may wish to read this [answer by Joubarc](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/249/132).

Comment: That's what I thought, when the Bricklink name referred to the the, 'inside stud holder,' I hadn't connected it to the tiny notches inside the brick, I was looking for a tube of some kind.